# Middle clicking tabs always shows the scrolling icon

Tags: windows, windows-10, google-chrome, mouse

I have upgraded to windows 10 and sometimes my mouse works normally and sometimes I am unable to middle click tabs to close them. This is not just an issue in chrome but also in any app that has tabs. When I middle click a tab I just get the round icon with 4 arrows for scrolling

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This might be because of how your mouse settings are configured in Windows.

Try the following:

Go to Mouse settings in control panel (its still available in Windows 10). Use one of the below paths:

- `Control Panel > All Control Panel Items > Mouse`
- `Control Panel > Hardware and Sound > Mouse` under "Devices and Printers"

[image: Mouse settings in All Control Panel Items]
[image: Mouse settings under Hardware and Sound]

Check your middle click settings in Mouse Properties window.

If you or your manufacturer have installed a custom mouse driver, an additional tab might be present (not seen in below screenshot) or check further by visiting the Hardware tab and select your mouse driver > Properties .

[image: Mouse Properties > Hardware tab]

A similar problem happened to me on my laptop, and i had to change my touchpad settings to make the middle click work right (when i press right and left click at the same time). On my laptop, Touchpad settings were in a separate tab next to Hardware in mouse properties.

Comment: For anyone else having the same problem. I also had to manually delete c:\program files\synaptic

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly the same problem when upgrading to Windows 10.

In fact, the problem was that my mouse came with software from the manufacturer
which was disabled by the upgrade.

In my case, simply re-installing the software fixed the problem.
I had the same problem with other products and drivers that just needed
re-installation. I had to repeat the operation for some of the products
after every major upgrade of Windows 10.

If you have difficulties finding the right software for your mouse,
let us know its details so we can help.